# Add self signed certificate using PHPMailer on Gmail account

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

Is it possible to use self signed or dedicated certificates on a Gmail account with the library PHPMailer? How to do this? And is this a secure option?

Comment: Yes, you can do this - see @elcid9's answer. No it's not secure, by definition. Generally self-signed certificates are not for public use; if you're intending to use it in the open, get a real cert. Take a look at startssl.com for a free one.

Comment: But how does it work? Does the retriever of the mail that is self signed need to accept the certificate before he can read it?

Comment: No, the receiver will usually display the message anyway (if it's just signed), but it will show a broken padlock icon or similar, i.e. it's not providing any guarantee that the sender is who they say they are because there is no chain of trust leading to a CA. It's just like visiting a web page with a self-signed cert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do :

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->AddAddress("contact@example.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "Test";

$mail->sign_cert_file = "/cert/key.pem";
$mail->sign_key_file = "/key/key.pem";
$mail->sign_key_pass = "password";

$mail->Send();
```

But, i don't know if Google gonna accept your certificate...

**Code Source : http://www.adam-makes-websites.com/discoveries/sending_secure_certified_s-mime_emails_via_php**